# Filter self-join table with infinite levels EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to filter the name property for the following self-join table that has an infinite levels:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

The query must get all matched rows and if it happens that if there are matched rows were children it should retrieve all its parents too until level zero.

Here is an example of the data that I may have:

```
Id    ParentId    Name       
--------------------------
1     null        test        
2     1           test1           
3     2           test           
4     null        test2           
5     3           test3          
6     4           test4           
7     2           test           
8     3           test5           
9     1           test2
```

Comment: It should be recursive CTE query. I can show example if you ok to execute raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating the tree

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;



namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Category category = new Category();
            category.Load();
            category.MakeTree();

        }
        public class Category
        {
            public Category root { get; set; }
            public static List<Category> categoryList { get; set; }
            public int? Id { get; set; }
            public int? ParentId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<Category> children { get; set; }

            public void Load()
            {
                categoryList = new List<Category>()
                {
                    new Category() {Id =  1, ParentId = null, Name = "test" },
                    new Category() {Id =  2, ParentId = 1, Name = "test1" },
                    new Category() {Id =  3, ParentId = 2, Name = "test" },
                    new Category() {Id =  4, ParentId = null, Name = "test2" },
                    new Category() {Id =  5, ParentId = 3, Name = "test3" },
                    new Category() {Id =  6, ParentId = 4, Name = "test4" },
                    new Category() {Id =  7, ParentId = 2, Name = "test" },
                    new Category() {Id =  8, ParentId = 3, Name = "test5" },
                    new Category() {Id =  9, ParentId = 1, Name = "test2" }
                };
            }
            public void MakeTree()
            {
                root = new Category();
                root.Id = null;
                root.Name = "Root";
                MakeTreeRecursive(root);
            }
            void MakeTreeRecursive(Category parent)
            {
                List<Category> categories = categoryList.Where(x => x.ParentId == parent.Id).ToList();
                foreach (Category category in categories)
                {
                    if (parent.children == null) parent.children = new List<Category>();
                    parent.children.Add(category);
                    MakeTreeRecursive(category);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How that will filter by name?! Also I do not have categoryList  and children members

Comment: You don't have a tree and need additional properties for the tree.  To filter you have to write code to search the tree.